# NullReferenceException С# При попытке заполнения

Tags: c#

Возникла необычная проблема.
Имеется класс:

```
public class QuestionList //Класс хранения вопросов  
{
public string question; //Вопросы
public string[] answers = new string[4]; //Ответы 4
}
```

Необходимо при нажатии кнопки, загружать вопросы. (В данном случае из базы данных, но проблема не в этом).

```
public void OnClickPlay() //При нажатии кнопки запуска
...       
{   
for(int k=0; k<1; k++){
questions[k].question = guestI[k];
}
int c =0;
for(int i=0; i<guestI.Length; i++){
 for(int a=0; a<=3; a++){
    questions[i].answers[a] = ansI[c];
    c++;
}}}
```

Так вот, проблема в том, что если мы создаем его в общих переменных:

```
public QuestionList[] questions;
```

И затем задаем размер в void Start:

```
void Start () {
    questions  = new QuestionList [2];
}
```

то все работает. Однако, если задаем размер в самом **OnClickPlay**, то выдает ошибку **NullReferenceException**.

Посоветуйте решение данной проблемы.

*P.S.* Задавать размер в **void Start** не выйдет, ибо количество вопросов будет зависеть от данных, которые передаются при нажатии кнопки (разные по размеру)

Comment: Помимо массива существует целая куча коллекций на все случаи жизни. Познакомьтесь хотя бы с `List`

Comment: А где у вас по OnClick происходит инициализация массива?

Comment: добавлю к предыдущему комментарию немного конкретики: используйте var questions = new list<QuestionList>(); потом создайте объект класса QuestionList ql, заполните его и используйте метод questions.Add(ql)

Comment: Благодарю, сейчас попробую при помощи List

Answer (score 0):

Да. Спасибо, использование List действительно решило проблему. (Чего я с самого начала его не юзал >_<).

```
  public void OnClickPlay(){  
  List<QuestionList> questions = new List<QuestionList>();
  ...
  for(int k=0; k<guestI.Length; k++){
    questions.Add(new QuestionList() {question=" "});
    questions[k].question = guestI[k];
    }
  ...
  }
```

Comment: почему бы сразу не передавать `question=guestI[k]` в инициализатор раз уж решили его использовать?